# Eloquent query correctly eager loads relation, but when I try to dump the related object I get only the ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hey guys I'm trying to grab a relation from the Friend model (pivot for user friends). When I try to dump the relation of the Friend object I should be getting a User model, instead it dumps only the ID of the User.

Here is the Friend Model:

```
class Friend extends Eloquent
{
    public function requester()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Acme\Users\User', 'requester');
    }
}
```

Here is friend repo:

```
public function getFriendRequests($id, $onlyAccepted = false)
{
    return Friend::where('acceptor', $id)->with('requester')->get();
}
```

Here is FriendsController:

```
$friendAccepts = $this->friendRepo->getFriendAccepts(Auth::id(), true);
dd($friendAccepts[0]->acceptor);
```

It should be dumping a User object but I'm only getting the ID of the user when I do:

> int 101

Here is output when I `dd($friendAccepts[0]);`
(It correctly shows the relation eager loaded as a User object

```
object(Acme\Friends\Friend)[513]
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'requester' (length=9)
      1 => string 'acceptor' (length=8)
      2 => string 'status' (length=6)
      3 => string 'created_at' (length=10)
      4 => string 'updated_at' (length=10)
  protected 'table' => string 'friends' (length=7)
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => int 1
      'requester' => int 101
      'acceptor' => int 1
      'status' => int 2
      'created_at' => string '2014-05-02 22:53:35' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-07-31 12:56:53' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => int 1
      'requester' => int 101
      'acceptor' => int 1
      'status' => int 2
      'created_at' => string '2014-05-02 22:53:35' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-07-31 12:56:53' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=1)
      'acceptor' => 
        object(Acme\Users\User)[318]
          protected 'fillable' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
          protected 'table' => string 'users' (length=5)
          protected 'hidden' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected 'connection' => null
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
          protected 'perPage' => int 15
          public 'incrementing' => boolean true
          public 'timestamps' => boolean true
          protected 'attributes' => 
            array (size=16)
              ...
          protected 'original' => 
            array (size=16)
              ...
          protected 'relations' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'visible' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'appends' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'guarded' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'dates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'touches' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'observables' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'with' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'morphClass' => null
          public 'exists' => boolean true
          protected 'pendingEvents' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'appends' => 
    array (size=0)
  empty
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '*' (length=1)
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'touches' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'observables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'morphClass' => null
  public 'exists' => boolean true
  protected 'pendingEvents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

UPDATE:

When I use toArray() and access acceptor as a keyed array element it dumps the user object's properties.

```
dd(Friend::where('requester', Auth::id())->with('acceptor')->first()->toArray()['acceptor'])
```

Output:

```
array (size=7)
  'id' => int 1
  'requester' => int 101
  'acceptor' => 
    array (size=14)
      'id' => int 1
      'email' => string 'nader.verla@johnston.com435' (length=27)
      'fname' => string 'April' (length=5)
      'lname' => string 'Macejkovic' (length=10)
      'username' => string 'AprilMacejkovic40466' (length=20)
      'birthday' => string '2006-12-02' (length=10)
      'gender' => string 'Male' (length=4)
      'location' => string 'Port Noelside' (length=13)
      'website' => string 'pagacvandervort.net' (length=19)
      'bio' => string 'Ut ut quia vitae vero. Sit eligendi voluptate quia. Voluptas ea accusamus fuga officiis sunt. Sed est fugiat et et voluptas. Distinctio vero error aliquid. Ipsam et tempora asperiores temporibus in autem.' (length=204)
      'profile_picture' => string '' (length=0)
      'created_at' => string '2013-10-18 09:49:31' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-03-05 04:17:24' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
  'status' => int 2
  'created_at' => string '2014-05-02 22:53:35' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2014-07-31 12:56:53' (length=19)
  'deleted_at' => null
```

Comment: where is the acceptor relation ?

Comment: protected relations => array (size=1) 'acceptor' => object(Acme\Users\User)[318]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not want to have relationship methods named the same as table "attributes"(fields) if you plan on using dynamic properties to access those methods.

There is already a mechanism in place to resolve the dynamic properties and inaccesible properties using `__get($key)` which calls `getAttribute($key)`. The first thing it checks for is if the key exists in the `$attributes` of the model instance and returns it if it does. This will stop it from continuing to check if there is a relation loaded with that name or if there is a method to call with a camel case version of that key.

"This allows every attribute to dynamically accessed through the _get method without accessors."

**Ref**

[Eloquent Model API](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html)

[Eloquent Model @__get](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2970)

[Eloquent Model @getAttribute](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2371)